# HttpClient not sending post data to NancyFX endpoint

Tags: asp.net-core, data-binding, dotnet-httpclient, nancy

I am doing some integration testing of my web API that uses NancyFX end points. I have the xUnit test create a test server for the integration test

```
 private readonly TestServer _server;
    private readonly HttpClient _client;

    public EventsModule_Int_Tester()
    {
        //Server setup
        _server = new TestServer(new WebHostBuilder()
      .UseStartup<Startup>());
        _server.AllowSynchronousIO = true;//Needs to be overriden in net core 3.1
        _client = _server.CreateClient();
    }
```

Inside a Test Method I tried the following

```
   [Fact]
    public async Task EventTest()
    {
        // Arrange
        HttpResponseMessage expectedRespone = new HttpResponseMessage(System.Net.HttpStatusCode.OK);
        var data = _server.Services.GetService(typeof(GenijalnoContext)) as GenijalnoContext;

        //Get come random data from the DBcontext
        Random r = new Random();
        List<Resident> residents = data.Residents.ToList();
        Resident random_residnet = residents[r.Next(residents.Count)];

        List<Apartment> apartments = data.Apartments.ToList();
        Apartment random_Apartment = apartments[r.Next(apartments.Count)];



        EventModel model = new EventModel()
        {
            ResidentId = random_residnet.Id,
            ApartmentNumber = random_Apartment.Id

        };

        //Doesnt work
        IList<KeyValuePair<string, string>> nameValueCollection = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> {
        { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ResidentId", model.ResidentId.ToString()) },
        { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("ApartmentNumber", model.ApartmentNumber.ToString())}
        };

        var result = await _client.PostAsync("/Events/ResidentEnter", new FormUrlEncodedContent(nameValueCollection));



        //Also Doesnt work 
        string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model, Formatting.Indented);
        var httpContent = new StringContent(json, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        var response = await _client.PostAsync("/Events/ResidentEnter", httpContent);

        //PostAsJsonAsync also doesnt work 

        // Assert
        Assert.Equal(response.StatusCode, expectedRespone.StatusCode);
    }
```

The NancyFX module does trigger the endpoint and receives the request but without the body

[image: Img1]

What am I doing wrong? Note that the NancyFX endpoint has no issue transforming a Postman call into a valid model.

The NancyFX endpoint
[image]

Comment: Can you show the API signature on the `/Events/ResidentEnter` endpoint?

Comment: @Andy Updated the question with the endpoint API

Comment: You said PostMan has no problems, can you also show what you are doing in PostMan?

Comment: @Andy I am just sending the EventModel properties as paramaters trough the body  in the shape of form-data. Note both form-data and x-www-form-urlencoded work. I can add a picture if you want

Comment: If it works in PostMan, but it's not working here... AND your actual endpoint is getting hit in your tests (means your httpclient host is setup correctly), then it has to be that you are not posting the data the same way as you are in PostMan.

Comment: @Andy I assumed the same form the start, but no matter what I search for there are only a few ways to post it and none of them work for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I fixed it, for those curious the issue was that the NancyFX body reader sometimes does not properly start reading the request body. That is that the stream reading position isn't 0 (the start) all the time.

To fix this you need to create a CustomBoostrapper and then override the ApplicationStartup function so you can set up a before request pipeline that sets the body position at 0

Code below

```
    protected override void ApplicationStartup(TinyIoCContainer container, IPipelines pipelines)
    {
        base.ApplicationStartup(container, pipelines);
        pipelines.BeforeRequest.AddItemToStartOfPipeline(ctx =>
        {
            ctx.Request.Body.Position = 0;
            return null;
        });


    }
```